# Convert date to day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe and I want to have a column for weekdays based on dates. My data frame is like this:

```
     Location        Date_Time          Volume
0  Perkins-YMCA, 2017-07-01 00:00:00      34
1  Perkins-YMCA, 2017-07-01 00:15:00      30
2  Perkins-YMCA, 2017-07-01 00:30:00      23
3  Perkins-YMCA, 2017-07-01 00:45:00      26
4  Perkins-YMCA, 2017-07-01 01:00:00      21
```

I first separate the dates and time and created a separate column as below:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.date
```

but when I use

```
df['Weekdays']=df['Date'].dt.dayofweek
```

I receive this error:

```
Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?
```

I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use this : `df['Weekdays'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.dayofweek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt.date` returns a series of `object` dtype with cells being Python's `datetime.datetime` type, so you can't do `dt.dayofweek`. You can do:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.floor('D')
```

and you get a `Datetime` dtype, and the subsequent `df['Date'].dt.daysofweek` should work.

On the other note, if you insist on `datetime.datetime` type, you can convert your `Date_Time` column to `datetime` type:

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df['Date'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.date
df['Weekdays'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.daysofweek
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.dt.dayofweek` after [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) when values convert to `datetime`. When you store `.dt.date` you change type of `dtype: datetime64[ns]` to `dtype: object`. for applying `dt.(anythings)` you need to have values as `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

```
df['Weekdays'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']).dt.dayofweek
print(df)
```

---

```
       Location            Date_Time  Volume  Weekdays
0  Perkins-YMCA  2017-07-01 00:00:00      34         5
1  Perkins-YMCA  2017-07-01 00:15:00      30         5
2  Perkins-YMCA  2017-07-01 00:30:00      23         5
3  Perkins-YMCA  2017-07-01 00:45:00      26         5
4  Perkins-YMCA  2017-07-01 01:00:00      21         5
```